# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when initializing array objects

Tags: java, android, arrays, initialization, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a custom class and I create an array from it in a classic fashion. but when I try to access and initialize its individual elements I get the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. In a nutshell the following simple lines create trouble for me in android:

```
Coordinate[] test;
test = new Coordinate[]{}; // I still get the error without having this line
test[0]= new Coordinate(4,5);
```

I need to initialize my objects in the array in a dynamic way in a for loop.
so `test = new Coordinate[]{cord1,cord2};` , although it works, will not solve my problem.

P.S. I know how to use ArrayList object and I use it in my other parts of the code.
But I am somewhat forced to create Coordinates in a classic way.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a non empty array :

```
test = new Coordinate[size];
```

Where `size` > 0.

Otherwise, your array is empty, and `test[0]` causes the exception you got.

This should also work (assuming you only want one element in your array) :

```
Coordinate[] test = new Coordinate[]{new Coordinate(4,5)};
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify size of the array.

For example in order to create an array of size 10, you'd write:

```
Coordinate[] test;
test = new Coordinate[10]; // Creating array of size 10
test[0]= new Coordinate(4,5);
```

Remember that 'classic' arrays are of fixed size.

Comment: where that could solve the problem, I still dont know the size of my array. is there a way to create it dynamically?

Comment: @user2770916 Unfortunately not. In order to have a dynamic size array, you'd use `ArrayList`. If you really need to use 'normal' arrays, you need to estimate what could be the largest size of an array and set its size to this number.

Answer (score 0):

Array are contiguous block of memory so you should mention the array size (non -negative)

```
new Coordinate[size];
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot to specify the array size:

```
Coordinate[] test;
test = new Coordinate[20]; // <-- array of size 20
test[0]= new Coordinate(4,5);
```

Remember that arrays are of fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

`test = new Coordinate[]{};` is the same as `test = new Coordinate[0];`

You are creating an array of length zero and then try to access its first member.

You will have at least to create a length 1 array:

```
test = new Coordinate[0];
```

our using your scheme :

```
test = new Coordinate[]{new Coordinate(4,5)};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers.
I think I will solve the problem in the following way:
1. dynamically determine the size of my array
2. initialize my array with that size.